# Firebase Audience Edit and Delete Disabled

Tags: firebase, firebase-analytics, firebase-console

After creating an audience I can't edit or delete it.

Every option is greyed out after pressing edit (except for the "Add a description" option):
[image: Greyed out options in Firebase Audience edit]

How can I delete or edit an audience?
Thanks for any information in advance :)

Comment: hit into this myself too, and I'm curious about this. Did you get any answer anywhere?

Comment: @tropicalfish No info whatsoever... I understand why editing might be disabled as the audience takes a while to populate but not being able to delete it is weird.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. Any update on this?

Answer (score 5):

It's not possible. After you have created an Audience, you can only edit the Name or the description. You can't edit any of the conditions, so you need to create a new audience if you want set other conditions.

> Edit an audience After you create an audience, you can edit only the
> name and description.

[Audiences - Firebase Help](https://support.google.com/firebase/answer/6317509?hl=en)

Also, you can't delete an Audience, only archive it. If you reach the limit of 100 audiences, you need to archive any audience and wait 24/48 hours to create a new audience.